# periodicity, minimum phase, maximum phase, interpretation

Tags: z-transform

I have a finite linear difference equation

$$y(n)=ax(n-1)+bx(n-2)+cx(n-3)+\ldots+fx(n-m)\text,$$

relating an input $x(n)$ to an output $y(n)$. If I assume periodicity of type $x(n-2)=x(n)$, the right hand side reduces to a summation over $x(n-1)$ and $x(n-2)$  (where $x(n-2)=x(n)$) and the collective coefficients  say $A$ and $B$:

$$y(n)=AX(n-1)+Bx(n)$$

($y(n)$ then also has period $2$.)

Applying the $\mathcal Z$-transform to this and exploring the zeros (poles just at $z=0$) I would like to make comments on the coefficients predicting that a period 2 system is possible.

How can I do this regarding zeros inside/outside the unit circle ?

Comment: Could you clarify this sentence: "I would like to make comments on the coefficients predicting that a period 2 system is possible"? I'm not sure I understand what it exactly is that you want to achieve.

Comment: Experimentally I observed that if the zeros (poles of the inverse transfer function) are all outside the unit circle, then the coefficients A and B support a period two input and output. For a different set a,b,c,  and hence different A and B, where zeros are not all outside, the input and output do not have a period two pattern. I have tested this for other periodic scenarios and zeros of G(z) (or poles of 1/G(z)) all outside the unit circle for the new arrangement of coefficients confirmed that periodic prediction -  how can I explain this?

Comment: If the input is periodic with period 2 then the output must be periodic with period 2 as well (apart from transients). I think I still don't exactly understand what the question is. What is given and what would you like to compute? And what is a "period 2 system"?

Comment: Hi @Michelle, I just had to add a few empty lines to mark paragraphs, and a few $ to mark formulas, to make your question readable. Please feel encouraged to give future posts more structure! Furthermore, I also don't  understand the question. "making comments" is not really something I know how to help you with.

Comment: rephrase - Is it possible (and are there criteria) that the impulse response (the coefficients of the difference equation) of a BIBO system has a part to play in creating periodic tendencies (not neccessarlly related to that of the input) observed in an output ?

Comment: I have reasons to believe that one can predict the likelyness  of a certain periodicity to be present in an output by evaluating the coefficients of the difference equation with no knowledge of the input except that it is bounded.

Comment: You can have (decaying) transients with a certain frequency, but not with a non-recursive first order system as in your question. You would need a second order recursive system with poles away from the origin. Take a look at [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/38199/4298) to a related question.

Comment: I understand now - it answers my question!

Comment: We don't :( ${}$

Comment: Yes it helped  me :) go in piece!

Comment: Sorry, that comment reminded me of this silly song. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vPWE2Ebz48

Comment: @Michelle Please post your own answer to your question when the system lets you! It may help someone in the future (and you can use it for reference).